# Import a module in root module or root component

Tags: angular

I have a third party library to control the layout of an angular app. I figured it should be imported somewhere that can be accessed through the whole app.
Is there any difference that I import it in app.module.ts (the root module), or import it in app.component.ts (the root component) ?

Comment: Are you referring to ES modules? Or Angular modules? And when you say "import" are you referring to the import statement (ES import) or the NgModule import array. You can only import Angular modules using the import array in other Angular modules, not components.

Comment: @DeborahK It it an angular module. I saw some codes like " import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; ", aren't they importing angular modules to a component?

Comment: The import statement in your code is the ES 2015 import statement. It is importing classes from the defined libraries, not importing the modules themselves. You need to import the modules using the imports array in one of your Angular modules.

Comment: I have a video that details the differences between ES 2015 modules and Angular modules that may help clarify: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Comment: @DeborahK Seems like that's what I've been confused about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modules, components, and services should always be imported through another Module. Making the declaration inside of the module not only allows for better modularity, but allows components to *see* other components, as well as allows for *singleton* services (may term may be incorrect, but the jist isn't).

If you have more questions about modules, [please read this](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq). I will say that everything depends on the library you are using, so if you let me know I can go into more detail.

Comment: It seems I got wrong about ES import and angular import. Thanks anyway!